# NSString object returns nil value

Tags: ios, google-maps, nsstring, nsurl

```
NSString *main = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.co.in/maps?q=restaurants&sll=%f,%f&radius=50&output=json",objRestaurantFinderAppDelegate.currentLatitude,objRestaurantFinderAppDelegate.currentLongitude];

NSError *error;
NSURL *mainUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:main];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:mainUrl encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
```

Comment: the link is not working. Tats why "str" shows NULL. Check the link twice

Answer (score 2):

You can use as

```
NSURL *mainURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/maps?q=restaurants&sll=23.03957,72.56600&radius=10&output=json"];
```

Comment: you can use another for testing like this "http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"

Comment: If you want to add something to the answer, feel free to use the **edit** button :-)

Comment: What point are you trying to make with this answer?  Please highlight it as you just appear to be trying to save whitespace.

Comment: Google link is not working, use another link then check.

Answer (score 1):

> In your case Just do

```
NSURL *mainUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:main];
```

Comment: Looks like your link is not working, I checked with the links with image it doesn't return null.